# rails and highcharts column chart

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

hi im really stuck im using highcharts in my rails app and trying to get a column chart to show how many male users i have compared to female users in my database but cant seem to figure out how to get the data to read from my users database table. here is my user model

```
def self.gender_analysis(gender)
  User.where(:gender => MALE).count
  User.where(:gender => FEMALE).count
end
```

here is my user.js file where i crate the chart

```
$(function(){
   new Highcharts.Chart({
     chart:{
       renderTo: "pie_chart",
       type:"column"
       },
       title: { text: "Gender" },
       xAxis: { type: "percent correct"},
       yAxis: {    
       title: { text: "Gender" }
    },
          series: [{
            data: <%= users.each do |user| %>
            }]
      });
   });
```

and my user view.html.erb looks like

```
<div id="pie_chart" style="width:568px; height:300px;"></div>
<h1>Listing users</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Hobby</th>
      <th>Created</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead> 
<tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.number %></td>
        <td><%= user.gender %></td>
        <td><%= user.hobby %></td>
        <td><%= user.created_at %></td>
```

i am new to rails developing and will appreciate any help given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple:
In your `view`, I mean in your `html.erb` put:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

And also add `script`:

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Total User'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: Unknown'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Male', 'Female'],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total Number',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
               name: 'Users',
               data: [<%= User.where(:gender => 'MALE').count %>, <%= User.where(:gender => 'FEMALE').count %>]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Also here check out the Fiddle.

[**http://jsfiddle.net/C5YAX/**](http://jsfiddle.net/C5YAX/)

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Thanks for your help your a life saver

Answer (score 0):

This should be like this:

```
def self.gender_analysis(gender)
  User.where(:gender => MALE).count if gender == :male
  User.where(:gender => FEMALE).count if gender == :female
end
```

Then in your ERB file you should have this:

```
$(function(){
   new Highcharts.Chart({
     chart:{
       renderTo: "pie_chart",
       type:"column"
       },
       title: { text: "Gender" },
       xAxis: { type: "percent correct"},
       yAxis: {    
       title: { text: "Gender" }
    },
     ,
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Gender Split',
            data: [
                ['Female',   <%= User.gender_analysis(:female) %>],
                ['Male',     <%= User.gender_analysis(:male) %>]
            ]
        }]
      });
   });
```

Comment: hi for some reason the chart wont appear for me still it comes up blank in my view file

Comment: What does your html/JS look like?

Comment: hi i was just calling everything with this div in my index.html file the above answer seems to work for me thanks for your help <div id="pie_chart" style="width:568px; height:300px;"></div>